# C++ template method to specialize union types

Tags: c++, templates, unions

Suppose I have a union:

```
union U{
    int i;
    float f;
};
```

I want to write a generic method that uses it as a float or int. Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T sum(std::vector<U> vec){
    T res(0);
    for (U &v: vec){
        res += ... // use v.i or v.f depending on what T is
    }
    return res;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? This was just an example method. I have a much longer, complicated method, and I don't want to duplicate it just to switch which union type it is using.

Comment: Why are you saying `typedef`?

Comment: I forgot you could name unions without a typedef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specialization would work:

```
template <typename T> T const & get(U const &);

template <> int const & get<int>(U const & u) { return u.i; }
template <> float const & get<float>(U const & u) { return u.f; }
```

Usage:

```
for (U & v : vec) { res += get<T>(v); }
```

Comment: Interesting; I was thinking about something similar. Would you say this is the cleanest way of doing something like this?

Comment: @Azmisov: Given you start with having a vector of unions (!), i'd say we're long past doing things cleanly!